# Running Hadoop examples halt in Pseudo-Distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

Every thing run well in Standalone mode and when going to the pseudo-distributed mode, the HDFS works well, I can put files to HDFS and browse it. And I also checked that there is one DataNode in the live nodes lists.

However, when I run `bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`, the program just halt there without producing any error. And from `http://ereg.adobe.com:50070/dfsnodelist.jsp?whatNodes=LIVE` I can see that nothing has ever been run on that DataNode.

I followed the configuration in the tutorial for those xml conf files. So anyone have any idea about what other mistakes I might have made? B.T.W, I'm running the stuffs on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

By halt, do you mean it hangs, or that it just silently returns?  For Mapreduce issues, you should check the JobTracker's webpage (at port 50030) to see the status of the submitted job.