# Hadoop - examples contained in examples jar fail to complete in Pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Having some problems with map reduce running in pseudo-distributed mode.  I am running version 1.2.1 on linux.  I have:
1. created $JAVA_HOME & $HADOOP_HOME and added the relative bin directories to the path;
2. Formatted the dfs;
3. executed start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh.

Executing jps seems to show everything running that should be running (I think).

```
[paul@lt001 bin]$ jps
8724 TaskTracker
8487 SecondaryNameNode
8841 Jps
8353 DataNode
7239 NameNode
8597 JobTracker
```

I have then tried to run the wordcount and pi examples with similar results, eg:

```
[paul@lt001 bin]$ hadoop jar hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar pi 4 1000
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Number of Maps  = 4
Samples per Map = 1000
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Starting Job
13/11/18 10:31:38 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
13/11/18 10:31:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201311181028_0001
13/11/18 10:31:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/11/18 10:31:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
13/11/18 10:31:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

In each instance the output reaches the map 100% reduce 0% stage then stalls.  No matter how long I wait the job does not advance any further.  I have checked the logs and the one I suspect is indicating the problem is hadoop-paul-tasktracker-lt001.log which has the following output:

```
2013-11-18 10:31:55,969 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 10:34:59,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 10:35:05,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 10:35:11,253 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 

..........

2013-11-18 11:10:03,259 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:06,290 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:12,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:18,343 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:21,369 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:27,395 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:33,426 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2013-11-18 11:10:36,463 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201311181028_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy >
```

This appears to be the same issue as here:

[Running Hadoop examples halt in Pseudo-Distributed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022294/running-hadoop-examples-halt-in-pseudo-distributed-mode)

Have checked the status on the JobTracker webpage and this running showing 4 completed map tasks and 1 running (0% complete after 40 minutes) reduce task.

It seems it is stuck on reduce > copy > but why?  Can anyone help with where to look next?

UPDATE

I think I have some more info.  If I look at the running reduce task

```
(http://localhost:50030/taskdetails.jsp?tipid=task_201311201256_0001_r_000000)
```

I see it is assigned to machine /default-rack/hit-nxdomain.opendns.com

If I then try and click on the "Last 4KB Task Logs" link it sends me to

```
http://hit-nxdomain.opendns.com:50060/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201311201256_0001_r_000000_0&start=-4097
```

amending this URL to

```
http://localhost:50060/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201311201256_0001_r_000000_0&start=-4097
```

then shows the log with many examples of the following:

```
2013-11-20 14:59:54,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Penalized(slow) Hosts: 
2013-11-20 14:59:54,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: hit-nxdomain.opendns.com Will be considered after: 814 seconds.
2013-11-20 15:00:54,729 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201311201256_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 4 map output(s) where 0 is already in progress
2013-11-20 15:00:54,729 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201311201256_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (1 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2013-11-20 15:00:54,730 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Penalized(slow) Hosts: 
2013-11-20 15:00:54,730 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: hit-nxdomain.opendns.com Will be considered after: 754 seconds.
```

So it seems that hadoop thinks the task is running on the hit-nxdomain.opendns.com host.

The host (localhost) picks it's DNS settings up via DHCP with the router set as the DNS server.  The router in turn uses opendns.com to resolve external addresses.

Am I right in thinking this is therefore a DNS issue?

Any idea how hadoop has ended up with this host name?

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: did you try to run your task in standalone mode? (trying this would assure you  that your code/data are correct)

Comment: many thanks for the response.  both jobs run in standalone mode.  i was able to resolve this issue.  See answer below.

Comment: hmm strange error - great that you were able solve it! I had also some troubles with hbase and NDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a DNS issue (with problems with the reverse lookup).  Resolution was as follows:

Check the task log for the "stalled" task (`via http://localhost:50030/`).  This showed up the issue with the DNS.

I found a stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082859/why-getting-hadoop-startup-safemodeexception/11090409#11090409) suggesting using

[hadoop-dns-checker](https://github.com/sujee/hadoop-dns-checker)

This showed that whilst the lookup/reverse lookup for localhost was fine, the same for the hostname was not working.  Fixing this fixed the problem.

The actual problem was that the host was getting it's IP via DHCP (via the router) which was separate from the (dnsmasq) dns server.  As such it was not registering the hostname with the DNS server.  Therefore dns lookups were being passed, by the dns server, upstream to our dns provider and a "dummy" IP address returned which then resolved to an opendns "not found" hostname.  MapReduce was using this hostname as the hostname for the reduce task. Enabling the dnsmasq dhcp and disbaling that on the router fixed the issue - the host now gets its IP address from dnsmasq and registers its hostname with the DNS server.  DNS lookup and reverse lookup now work for both localhost and the host/hostname.